# How to import existing CloudTrail in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I need to import an existing CloutTrail into AWS CDK. Usually there would be a function like fromLookup where I could supply name or ARN. However, for CloudTrail there is nothing. Only creating a new CloudTrail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems CloudTrail does not have this functionality, as a work around you should be able to create a Cloud watch rule out lined here https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6716